# How do I find the maximum element from a list in CLIPS?

Tags: list, max, clips

I am trying to find out the maximum element from a list, e.g.

```
(deffacts list 
   (list 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 6 5 4 3 2 1))
```

in CLIPS. How can I do that, in a very simple way, in a defrule?

Also, if I have a template for a patient, with the following slots :

```
(deftemplate patient
   (slot name)
   (slot age)
   (multislot tens_max)
   (multislot tens_min))

(deffacts data_patient
    (patient (name John) (age 22) (tens_max 13 15 22 11) (tens_min 6 7 14 6))
)
```

and I want to find out the maximum element from the last multislot, tens_min, how can I do that?

I would appreciate any suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **max** function to find the maximum value of its arguments. You can bind the list of numbers to a multifield variable in the conditions of a rule. The **max** function however expects separate arguments so you can't just pass it a multifield value. You can use the **expand$** function to split a multifield value into separate arguments for a function call. The **max** function expects at least 2 arguments in CLIPS 6.3 and at least 1 in CLIPS 6.4, so for completeness you would need to handle these cases. You can create a deffunction to handle these edge cases in your code.

```
         CLIPS (6.31 6/12/19)
CLIPS> 
(deffunction my-max ($?values)
   (switch (length$ ?values)
      (case 0 then (return))
      (case 1 then (return (nth$ 1 ?values)))
      (default (return (max (expand$ ?values))))))
CLIPS> 
(deffacts list 
   (list 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 6 5 4 3 2 1))
CLIPS> 
(defrule list-max
   (list $?values)
   =>
   (printout t "list max = " (my-max ?values) crlf))
CLIPS> 
(deftemplate patient
   (slot name)
   (slot age)
   (multislot tens_max)
   (multislot tens_min))
CLIPS> 
(deffacts data_patient
    (patient (name John) (age 22) (tens_max 13 15 22 11) (tens_min 6 7 14 6)))
CLIPS> 
(defrule patient-max
   (patient (tens_min $?values))
   =>
   (printout t "patient max = " (my-max ?values) crlf))
CLIPS> (reset)
CLIPS> (run)
patient max = 14
list max = 7
CLIPS>
```